# username & password database system (not using MySQL)

Tags: python, excel, database

Here's the deal. I don't want to use mySQL because I feel like it may just be more that I have to download. I have a lot of different modules downloaded including pandas, openpyxl, etc.

Essentially what I want to achieve is a database that I can write to on one program and on another program I would like to read that (like a registration and log in system). I've recently just got back into programming after leaving it after school. But have wanted to make something for a website I am working on. Just basic implementation.

So far I have this;

```
#-------------
#Introduction |
#-------------

print('Hello, Welcome to the account creation service!')
print('\nI just need to ask a few questions to assign you a username')
print('\n\n','*' * 15)

#--------------
#Key questions |
#--------------

firstname=input('What is your first name?: ')
print('\n','*' * 15)
lastname=input('What is your last name?: ')
print('\n','*' * 15)
date=input('Write down your date of birth ddmmyy without slashes: ')

#------------------
#Username Creation |
#------------------

print('\n','*' * 15)

username=(firstname[0:2] + lastname[0:2] + date)

print('\n','*' * 15)
print('\nCreating your username...')
input('\nPress enter to uncover your username: ')
print('\nyour username is: ',username.upper())

#------------------
#Password Creation |
#------------------

print('\n\nYou now need to create a password.')
password=input('\nPlease set a password: ')
print('\n\nPASSWORD SET\n')


input('\nPress enter to leave this page: ')

#------------------------
#Database Implementation |
#------------------------

import openpyxl

from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(filename = 'accountdatabase.xlxs')
```

Comment: Look into SQLite. It's included with your Python install.

Comment: [this will help you, in website creation, db maintence](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world)